# jquery, js show img on hover in map area, but also when selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I'm trapped at the moment. I think I'm almost there, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I've googled for a day now and I'm just stuck.

I have an image of a worldmap, with multiple images that are selectable. When you hover over a continent, it shows the selectable image. When you move around with your mouse again, it automatically doesn't show it anymore. So that's working.

[image: not selected]
[image: selected or hover]

What I'm trying now is that if I CLICK on the continent, the image stays there. And if I click again, it's deselected. Also you should be able to only have 1 continent selected. So if I decide to click on Europe, while Asia is selected, he should automatically deselect Asia.

My problem is that if one of them is working, the other one will be broken. If the hovering is working, the image won't stay selected on a click. And if you can click on the images, the hovering won't work anymore and he will select everything on every click (so not 1 continent at the time). He won't deselect the earlier clicked area.

**jQuery / js** (this is within my document.ready)

```
$(document).on('mouseover','map#world area',function(e){
    var el = $(this);
    var elclass = el.attr('class');
    $('.world-'+elclass).show();
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('mouseleave','map#world area',function(e){
    var el = $(this);
    var elclass = el.attr('class');
    $('.world-'+elclass).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('click','map#world area',function(e){
    var el = $(this);
    var elclass = el.attr('class');
    $('.world-'+elclass).show();
    $('select#continent').val(elclass).attr('selected','selected');

    $(elclass).off("mouseleave"); // aanpassen

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**PHP / HTML, within a form**

```
<map name="world" id="world">
    <div id="worldlayers">
        <img src="../images/world/world.jpg" alt="<?php echo EUROPE; ?>" usemap="#world" class="dblock" border="0"/>
        <img src="<?php echo BASEHREF; ?>images/world/south-america.png" usemap="#world" class="world-south-america" />
        <img src="<?php echo BASEHREF; ?>images/world/north-america.png" usemap="#world" class="world-north-america" />
        <img src="<?php echo BASEHREF; ?>images/world/asia.png" usemap="#world" class="world-asia" />
        <img src="<?php echo BASEHREF; ?>images/world/europe.png" usemap="#world" class="world-europe" />
        <img src="<?php echo BASEHREF; ?>images/world/australia.png" usemap="#world" class="world-australia" />
        <img src="<?php echo BASEHREF; ?>images/world/africa.png" usemap="#world" class="world-africa" />
    </div>

    <area class="south-america" shape="poly" coords="289,333,291,343,283,350,283,357,283,361,290,373,294,383,304,389,305,401,305,413,302,425,298,437,295,447,293,458,292,469,294,481,303,489,315,493,322,489,337,477,331,473,316,468,319,463,316,454,322,448,326,443,337,437,343,428,355,412,355,405,363,400,367,401,371,395,376,390,374,378,384,370,385,361,374,354,357,351,352,346,345,335,331,331,321,324,309,321,299,323,291,327" alt="south-america">
    <area class="north-america" shape="poly" coords="208,143,196,139,183,134,170,140,161,143,153,136,138,134,124,129,116,133,103,141,98,145,102,152,104,157,96,162,101,168,106,170,104,175,98,182,97,189,108,195,115,196,110,201,96,211,98,217,116,210,128,204,135,195,143,191,154,190,163,198,170,207,170,214,172,217,178,223,186,231,188,235,189,243,190,251,193,260,198,269,202,276,209,281,210,288,216,298,222,299,228,300,229,308,240,314,251,317,256,315,261,321,270,327,278,333,288,334,290,326,292,321,312,314,314,305,303,303,289,296,285,289,284,281,291,275,297,269,299,259,306,253,316,249,327,241,340,237,346,234,342,224,338,213,332,203,324,195,322,187,321,175,324,165,326,158,320,151,314,142,311,133,302,125,293,117,286,111,289,102,290,93,290,83,302,87,308,93,318,100,326,108,330,111,335,123,336,134,337,143,336,150,337,161,342,169,344,176,348,181,352,189,360,193,365,191,370,181,370,172,379,164,388,157,392,150,402,148,410,138,413,126,413,116,418,108,422,101,420,91,418,82,420,69,420,59,423,48,428,39,433,31,425,25,418,23,411,12,397,5,380,5,365,4,355,8,343,14,334,19,325,18,318,12,309,7,301,7,286,9,275,13,268,19,261,25,252,33,250,38,246,47,242,53,236,61,225,60,216,65,210,72,203,78,196,87,190,95,188,101,188,110,186,120,184,129,194,132,202,131,206,136" alt="north-america">
    <area class="africa" shape="poly" coords="442,266,438,273,432,278,434,284,429,287,425,291,420,299,421,305,421,310,417,318,421,328,428,333,434,338,440,341,450,341,458,338,466,338,472,341,476,345,470,351,476,358,479,364,484,373,480,383,481,389,485,395,486,405,488,413,492,418,494,427,502,428,509,428,517,425,522,419,525,412,528,406,533,399,545,400,549,406,557,404,561,394,562,387,566,377,561,372,553,379,544,376,542,368,542,362,542,356,549,348,556,342,560,337,566,327,565,323,556,325,549,325,543,317,539,311,534,304,531,296,526,289,524,283,523,280,510,279,503,275,497,280,489,275,484,272,481,269,479,263,464,263,456,266,448,267" alt="africa">
    <area class="europe" shape="poly" coords="428,167,425,161,422,157,414,157,405,157,401,163,402,167,408,173,415,177,423,181,438,196,440,202,438,207,432,210,433,217,436,225,442,222,444,227,442,232,448,237,452,241,441,243,434,248,435,255,435,259,438,264,444,266,454,264,456,259,460,256,466,251,470,249,472,259,478,259,482,263,488,267,495,261,499,263,503,268,512,272,516,269,511,263,509,257,514,254,518,249,520,244,523,241,528,243,534,240,536,245,542,247,548,250,554,253,562,255,558,248,558,241,562,237,558,233,554,228,557,226,562,223,566,219,571,221,576,224,580,223,582,219,579,211,577,206,577,201,582,191,581,185,582,176,582,169,587,163,594,153,593,143,588,139,584,133,578,130,576,125,576,121,578,112,583,105,588,101,594,97,599,95,606,91,603,87,598,39,590,34,583,31,572,32,564,36,554,40,526,46,511,47,500,44,490,49,479,54,476,57,476,65,479,71,482,77,483,83,489,90,496,110,497,119,500,129,501,136,490,139,484,146,482,149,484,153,481,163,478,167,470,173,465,178,464,185,464,192,467,197,470,200,472,204,472,209,467,214,459,219,455,212,452,204,451,198,454,189,456,185,449,180,432,171" alt="europe">
    <area class="australia" shape="poly" coords="756,353,757,368,758,373,758,383,752,383,748,379,750,373,743,372,734,370,728,375,721,378,716,383,712,387,700,393,696,397,696,404,698,409,700,417,702,421,700,426,708,428,715,425,720,424,727,421,734,421,743,424,744,431,749,429,752,435,757,438,762,441,763,449,768,453,774,449,778,443,809,461,813,464,820,460,824,454,828,449,832,445,836,439,837,434,831,428,828,424,820,393,817,383,815,377,811,369,798,362,784,355,775,349,765,351" alt="australia">
    <area class="asia" shape="poly" coords="756,369,754,353,746,349,738,348,734,343,730,335,726,325,721,317,718,310,716,301,725,295,731,293,735,288,740,280,744,276,753,273,758,269,759,263,761,256,761,253,767,250,771,245,780,241,787,233,789,228,798,219,803,209,807,201,809,194,818,190,830,184,841,180,840,170,845,164,852,169,856,169,860,165,861,157,852,153,843,144,848,133,844,127,836,128,832,133,827,139,818,137,810,140,800,137,798,133,790,129,784,132,777,123,782,102,775,97,766,93,756,91,744,92,745,103,749,109,752,116,752,125,743,125,736,123,732,115,724,111,719,110,714,116,708,113,703,109,699,99,698,89,691,85,689,79,686,72,683,63,676,57,670,48,664,41,662,34,654,35,650,39,650,43,649,51,650,57,656,64,661,67,666,71,668,75,670,83,670,92,662,89,654,93,648,97,640,101,632,105,631,112,625,113,612,114,605,117,602,122,600,133,601,137,603,149,594,143,594,152,592,158,586,167,583,171,582,175,582,182,582,185,582,191,580,197,578,203,581,211,581,220,580,225,571,224,566,219,558,224,556,228,561,237,568,238,570,243,567,247,570,255,570,262,560,261,557,254,550,251,544,251,537,253,533,251,526,252,520,253,515,253,510,258,511,263,515,268,520,267,527,267,530,267,532,270,531,276,530,279,523,279,528,286,534,289,536,293,538,297,540,301,545,311,548,317,548,323,557,318,569,313,576,308,581,302,582,301,587,295,594,294,600,299,607,301,610,303,612,307,613,316,618,322,619,331,626,337,632,337,633,331,630,326,629,319,632,313,638,309,645,306,654,306,658,313,652,323,655,333,658,343,665,350,672,357,680,363,696,367,704,369,719,371,732,369,740,367,746,363,748,367" alt="asia">
</map>
<?php echo CONTINENTQUOTE." ".$location."!"; ?><br>

<fieldset>
    <label for="destination"><?php echo DESTINATION.": "; ?></label>
    <select id="continent" name="continent">
        <option value="africa"><?php echo AFRICA; ?></option>
        <option value="europe"><?php echo EUROPE; ?></option>
        <option value="asia"><?php echo ASIA; ?></option>
        <option value="australia"><?php echo AUSTRALIA; ?></option>
        <option value="north-america"><?php echo NORTHAMERICA; ?></option>
        <option value="south-america" ><?php echo SOUTHAMERICA; ?></option>
    </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="horse" name="horse" value="horsename">Horsename
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="travel" value="<?php echo TRAVEL; ?>" class="yellow" />
</fieldset>
```

Btw, I'm a real beginner at javascript/jquery, so please explain what I need to do and why when you know how to fix my problem :)

Comment: I see two problems right off. First, you're removing your mousleave listener, `$(elclass).off("mouseleave")`, so your mousleaves aren't going to work after that point. Secondly, you just don't have any code to hide shown regions after another one is clicked. You'll have to write the code to do that.

Comment: That's what I meant with things I tried. I tried to remove the mouseleave, and then things kept staying selected and without it the hovering works but the clicks don't. I wrote code to show the region that was clicked on didn't I? Or is that wrong too? All the continents are always hidden, unless I say that they need to show. But even then, if it's clicked on (without the mouseleave event), it still doesn't show the selected image. I know that a part is working though, since the destination changes into the one that's clicked on. The moment I leave the area, the mouseleave event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should help you with your logic.

```
var clickedEl = null;
$(document).on('mouseover','map#world area',function(e){
    if ( !clickedEl ) {
      var el = $(this);
      var elclass = el.attr('class');
      $('.world-'+elclass).show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('mouseleave','map#world area',function(e){
    if ( !clickedEl ) {
      var el = $(this);
      var elclass = el.attr('class');
      $('.world-'+elclass).hide();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('click','map#world area',function(e){
    var el = $(this);
    if ( el == clickedEl ) {
      // it's the same el. hide it
      var elclass = el.attr('class');
      $('.world-'+elclass).hide();
      clickedEl = null; // nothing clicked anymore
    } else {
      // it's a different el
      // hide the old one
      var oldclass = clickedEl.attr('class');
      $('.world-'+oldclass).hide(); 
      // show the new one
      var elclass = el.attr('class');
      $('.world-'+elclass).show();
      $('select#continent').val(elclass).attr('selected','selected');
      clickedEl = el;  
    }  
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This kind-of worked, with the adjustments that Koen mentioned. I turned `var oldclass = clickedEl.attr('class');` into `var oldclass = $(clickedEl).attr('class');` The only thing that doesn't work now, is after 1 continent is selected, the hovering doesn't work anymore. But this looks quite nice too, so I think I'll leave it at this :)

Answer (score 0):

change **var clickedEl = null;** to **var clickedEl = false;** and 
**var oldclass = clickedEl.attr('class');** to **var oldclass = $(clickedEl).attr('class');**